# C++ Segmentation Fault when attempting to write to a vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

I have been having a rough time with this program, I am super rusty and it seems never learned a lot of things that I probably should have about pointers, memory management, and programming in general.

I am trying to make a program that uses the same two-dimensional vector of structures in multiple functions. To that end, I am passing this vector by reference to the initialization function, which will fill up the structures in the vector. If there is anything wrong with that approach, I would love to hear any better suggestions.

In any case, when the loop that I have set up to fill in the data tries to write to the structure, I get a segfault immediately. I'm sure that I'm trying to write to a weird art of memory, but it appears that I have a lesser understanding of memory usige in C++ than I thought I had.

I have looked around for this online and on StackOverflow, and I have tried implementing the solutions that I found to no avail. I have a really strong feeling that I am overlooking something really trivial, and will feel very sheepish (as I did with my last question) when it turns out I am a silly person. However, I am super frustrated and would like to figure this out, and I appeal to you awesome people.

Thanks for taking the time to read all this, just wanted to make an attempt at being thorough.

Here is the offending code, apologies for any wacky formatting, I am new to the site:

Here is the structure:

```
struct entry {
    int eTime;
    string eType;
    int pid;
};
```

This is the function that I am having trouble with:

```
void init(vector< vector<entry> > & pVect, vector< vector<entry> > & eVect){

entry newProcess;                      //to be added to the Process List
entry newEvent;                        //to be added to the Event List

int processNum;                        //For tracking number of processes in ProcessList
int eventNum;                //For tracking number of processes in Process List
string eTy;
int eTi;

cout << "Enter the command, then the number of cycles to be reserved for it." << endl;
cout << "Processing Input...";

int pid = -1;
int i = 0;
    while(cin >> eTy){
        cin >> eTi;

        if(eTy == "NEW"){
            cout << endl;
            pid++;
            cout << "DB: Process " << pid << ":" << endl;
            processNum = pid;

        newEvent.eType = "ARRIVAL";
        newEvent.eTime = 0;
        i = 0;
        }
        else{
            pVect.resize(10);
            pVect.at(pid).at(i).eType = eTy;
            pVect.at(pid).at(i).eTime = eTi;
            pVect.at(pid).at(i).pid = pid;

            cout << "Type: " << pVect[pid][i].eType << " | ";

            cout << "Time: " << pVect[pid][i].eTime << endl;

            i++;
        }
    }
  }
```

And for what it's worth, this is the main function:

```
int main(){


  int cpu = 2;

  vector< vector<entry> > processVector(10);
  vector< vector<entry> > eventVector(10);

  int processNum;
  int eventNum;

    init(processVector, eventVector);

    cout << endl << endl;


cout << "Process Vector - Original Order:" << endl;

//And then I'm going to output the actual process vector here, to make sure I've got the right idea.

 }
```

The input loop is set up so that I can hand-test entries or redirect STDIN to an input file. The inputs are one string, followed by one integer. Sample input would look something like this:

```
[input.txt]
NEW   5
CPU   100
INPUT 5000
CPU   80
SSD   1
CPU   30
NEW  100
CPU  20
SSD   0 
CPU   20
```

Comment: There are many inputs that would cause this crash, but without sample input it is difficult to tell what the *intended* input is. If you provide sample *valid* input it will be easier to assist you.

Comment: Your processVector and eventVector objects aren't given any initial size, nor resized, nor is any data pushed into them before you start indexing... of course they crash.  You should find a brief tutorial on vector usage.  Separately, `vector< vector<entry> > procList = pVect;` makes a copy of the (empty) input vector, so even if you do properly `push_back` values into it, the original vector is not updated and `procList` disappears when the `init` function returns: either make `procList` a reference or get rid of it and update `pVect` directly.

Comment: Merlin2011 - Thank you, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Tony D, I'll look into that, as well. I assumed it would be something simple.

Comment: Also, on looking at your comment again, Tony D, I definitely do need to get rid of the procList. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do :

```
procList[pid][i] = ...
```

You are accessing an `entry` object that does not exist yet : the `std::vector` default constructor makes it empty, it has a size of 0. This has **undefined behavior**.

---

**Solution**:

- You can use `resize()` to [add default elements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on your vectors (and their subvectors !)
- Or you can provide default elements at the [construction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of your vectors :
- Or you can use brace initializers to initialize your vector directly.

**Example:**

```
vector< vector<entry> > processVector(10); // will have 10 default constructed entry objects.
vector< vector<entry> > eventVector(10);   // will have 10 default constructed entry objects.

for(auto& v : processVector)
   v.resize(10);
for(auto& v : eventVector)
   v.resize(10);
```

---

**Notes:**

- You should check for the the return of each I/O operation
- Using the `at()` member function instead of `operator[]` on your vector will check the bounds for you, you would get something like ;

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  vector::_M_range_check

Comment: Okay, I am playing around with these ideas, would I want to change the vectors in my main() function to something like `vector< vector<entry> > processVector(10);`? After doing this, I am still having an error, thought the `at()` method does give me the error you describe.

Comment: Yes you need to to that, but also for each of your 10 subvectors you need to do it !

Comment: Oh, man, after playing around with that for a bit, I got it to work. Thank you! For the record, the issue was indeed that I had not resized the vector (and subvector). At first, I had not realized that the subvectors needed to be initialized that way, but I see that now. Thanks! It seems to work just fine, now, or at the very least, has stopped segfaulting.